# Convert an HTML variable with styles into a PDF in NodeJS, without using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

At my job I have been tasked with generating an HTML table with some styles and converting it to a PDF to then export it and send it via email. I tried Puppeteer and it work but we decided to change it so now I'm stuck trying a bunch of different libraries such as jsPDF without any result.

```
const html = await this.generateTablePDF();
const doc = new jsPDF();

doc.html(html);
const pdfBase64 = await doc.output("arraybuffer");

return await pdfBase64;
```

This is the jsPDF implementation I did. However, upon executing that code I getting a 'document is not defined' error.

Comment: something seems to be missing in your code.  Your error is `document is not defined` but none of your code has a `document` variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.